# How to set an installer icon for Adobe AIR applications?

Tags: air, installation, icons

I'm trying to set the installer icon of an Adobe AIR application, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

but I cannot figure out how to do it. I've specified the icons in the app.xml but nothing is showing up. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the icon images in the AIR packagee as well as reference them in the app.xml file. (Flash and Flash Builder should do this for you, but if you are packaging from the command line, it is easy to forget.) Make sure that they end up in the correct path within the package relative to the main app SWF or HTML file. I/e/ if you reference your icon as "foo/icon.png", it has to be in the "foo" subdirectory within the package.

Comment: You don't need a "native" package. An AIR package can include icons, too.